# Javascript custom event with user handler

Tags: javascript, html

As i can create custom event in javascript like this

```
var element = document.getElementById('MyElement');
var event = new Event('onrowclick');
element.onrowclick = rowclick();
element.dispatchEvent(event);

function rowclick(){
 //handler
}
```

But what if i want to let user call its own handler via attribute like this:

```
<div id="MyElement" onrowclick="MyNewRowClickHandler"></div>
function MyNewRowClickHandler(){
  //handler
}
```

jsfiddle demo will be best. Thanks

Comment: you meant `element.onrowclick = rowclick;` and not `element.onrowclick = rowclick();` right?
I am not sure using such an API is the right way to do, can't you use libraries such as jQuery to have user defined events so that you can attach more than one handler, and then look for attributes on the element to parse possible inline HTML handlers?

Comment: Huafu I can not use JQuery in my current project.

Comment: well, you'll need a library like sizzle at least to parse the DOM for elements with some custom attributes (here for example `[onrowclick]`) so that then you can `element.addEventListener('onrowclick', function(event){ window[event.currentTarget.onrowclick](event); })`

Comment: Event constructor may not be supported in IE.

Comment: You are right but i am strictly bounded with javascript.So that i must have to find solution with javascript only.

Comment: MrClan you are right but I'm not targeting IE but chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that particular case I believe you can capture `click` event on the container of all "rows", then check the `target` if it has an attribute `onrowclick`, and in that case run `window[onrowclick](event)`

Here is an example but you have to listen for the event another way in the case of IE, just to show the idea:

http://jsfiddle.net/huafu/366yfsjm/2/